# Detecting obvious endian issues

Tags: c, gcc, clang, endianness, portability

Consider the following code:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    unsigned int a = 0xdeadbeef;
    unsigned char *b = (unsigned char *) &a;

    printf("%x %x %x %x\n", b[0], b[1], b[2], b[3]);
    return 0;
}
```

Is there a gcc/clang (or any other compiler!) warning that I can enable that will tell me that this code will behave differently on big and little endian systems? I tried `-Wall` with gcc but it doesn't warn.

Of course implementing such a warning would involve deeper code analysis because in order to warn the compiler would have to realize that `b` is set to a pointer of `a` and then its individual bytes are accessed. But given the powerful code analysis and optimization skills of modern compilers, I'd expect such things to be possible.

FWIW, I know how to write endian-neutral code but apparently since big endian CPUs are becoming more and more obsolete many people don't seem care much about it any more and so I often have to fix lots and lots of endian issues when using components written for little endian on big endian systems.

I know it is pretty much impossible for the compiler to detect all endian issues but I think some, like the issue shown above, could be detected so that's why I'm wondering whether there are any warnings that could help me to detect endian issues. Or maybe there are some other tools that I could use to detect those issues?

Comment: No, there is no such warning. It would then warn about pretty much every single C program... :D

Comment: Lets remember that some CPUs can be either Big or Little Endian.    In any case, it is the responsibility of the programmer to be aware of what they are writing.  One way to help ensure correct accessing of the bytes of the variable is to make use of a `union` between the integer and the char array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though theoretically possible, it would probably be impractical for compilers to implement this feature. If you're looking for some way to automate checking for endianness issues, you will have to resort to [using a static analyzer](https://www.klocwork.com/resources/white-papers/address-endian-concurrency-issues) but even they would probably not do it to the level that you'd want.